# Node.js code isn't running in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, twilio

I'm working with Twilio and sending an example message when the provided code is ran in the terminal:

```
  var accountSid = '...'; 
  var authToken = '...';  

  var twilio = require('twilio');
  var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

  client.messages.create({
      body: 'Hello World!',
      to: '+1-555-555-5555',  // Text this number
      from: '+18885555555' // From a valid Twilio number
  })
  .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
```

However, when I place it in a function to be called on when a button is pressed, then nothing happens.

```
function messageNow() {
  var accountSid = '...';
  var authToken = '...';

  var twilio = require('twilio');
  var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

  client.messages.create({
      body: 'Hello World!',
      to: '+1-555-555-5555',  // Text this number
      from: '+18885555555' // From a valid Twilio number
  })
  .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
}
```

And call from HTML button:

```
<button type="submit" id="Btn" class="buttons" onclick="messageNow()">SUBMIT</button>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any errors in console? does the function get called at all (try logging something to console/use alert)?

Comment: How are you building the web application? You'll likely need some sort of build process if you want require to work, for example.

Comment: @Janar There's no errors within the console besides: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at messageNow (good.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: @KirkLarkin I essentially just copied and pasted the example 'get started' code Twilio has provided in the docs to test the sending functionality. It works when it's outside a function.

Comment: A button in NodeJS?? Are you aware Node runs server-side and does not have a DOM (no HTML, no buttons etc.) ? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Even when I try to run: node app.js in the terminal it no longer sends a message.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to Node.js but I was wanting to call the function that contains the code when the submit button is pressed in HTML which would send the verification text to the users phone.

Comment: But that's absolutely not how it works. Your button lives in the browser, and it will call a function in the browser (in your client-side javascript), not on your server directly. The client-side function will have to make a call to the server, for instance `$.post("/message")` and your Node app will have a router that will match this route : `app.post("/message", doSomething() )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds as though you are trying to run the [Twilio Node.js module](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) in the browser. This won't work as the module is only built for server side Node.js, not client side/browser JavaScript.

If you want to send messages via an interface with buttons, you will need to build a web application that can run the Twilio code on the server and present an interface in HTML, CSS and JavaScript that can call the server application.

There are a number of [tutorials that take you through different ways you can build apps to send SMS messages with Twilio and Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials?filter-product=sms&filter-language=node&order_by=-popularity_rank). It might help to take a look there.

Comment: Awesome! I'll check into it now.